# What is the meaning of pallet::compact in Pallet development

Tags: pallet

In this [code](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-how-to-guides/blob/main/example-code/template-node/pallets/mint-token/src/lib.rs), we can see the `pallet::compact` is used. So why we need this instruction?

quotes code:

```
#[pallet::weight(1_000)]
        pub fn transfer(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            to: T::AccountId,
            #[pallet::compact] amount: T::Balance,
        ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let sender_balance = Self::get_balance(&sender);
            let receiver_balance = Self::get_balance(&to);

            // Calculate new balances.
            let update_sender = sender_balance.saturating_sub(amount);
            let update_to = receiver_balance.saturating_add(amount);

            // Update both accounts storage.
            <BalanceToAccount<T>>::insert(&sender, update_sender);
            <BalanceToAccount<T>>::insert(&to, update_to);

            // Emit event.
            Self::deposit_event(Event::Transferred(sender, to, amount));
            Ok(().into())
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pallet::compact` is just a "shortcut" for writing `Compact<T::Balance>`.

[Compact](https://docs.rs/parity-scale-codec/latest/parity_scale_codec/struct.Compact.html) is a wrapper defined by `parity-scale-codec` to compact integers when being stored in their encoded format. So, that the entire transaction is a little bit smaller.

Comment: Is there a downside to this? Why is it not default?

Comment: Not every type can be compacted, so you can not use it by default. Downside is that you trade smaller storage requirements for more computational requirements (but they are really neglectable)